# Ubuntu 12.04 Unity High Resource Usage

Tags: 12.04, unity, ati

When I'm trying to switch windows by clicking on the icon in the Unity bar, it shows up the open windows and I can click on the one I want to switch to. But when I do that, my computer hangs up, for example if I'm playing music, the playback stutters.

I have a Radeon HD 7850, Phenom II X6 2.8ghz, 8 gb ddr3.

I'm not using the graphics driver from the Ubuntu repos because it's not working for some reason, I had to install the one from AMD's website. But still, Unity shouldn't be laggy while I'm transiting between windows.

Anything I can do to fix that?

Comment: Which graphic drivers do you have installed?

Comment: It's the latest 13.4 Proprietary from AMD's website.

Comment: I have better experience with13.04 than 12.04.
It seems a big improvement in Ubuntu side! If there is no obstacle consider upgrading!

Comment: It's always recommended to do a clear install, compared to the upgrade. If you are able to manage the drivers in 13.04 as in 12.04, the experience will be better because Unity is more debugged.

Comment: Alright thanks guys. I'm going to try and upgrade to 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

Unity and high-end graphics in general require a lot of RAM and CPU resources. I had this problem when I used Ubuntu 12.04. Upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 has fixed the issue - for me at least. In Ubuntu 12.04, Unity still had some bugs in the graphics that caused some inefficiencies.